# dot product in Matrix of Array in Java

Tags: java

I want to multiply (1 * n) and  (1* n)

```
 x = [x0,x1,x2]
 y = [
       y0,
       y1,
       y2
      ]
```

Want to multiply by row * column eg: x0*y0, x1*y1...
How can i iterate row into column. so that multiplication is expected.
getting confused.
Please help.

Comment: Those are 1 dimensional arrays (vectors, not matrices).  It makes no difference that you have split `y` over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

In that case is simple! I will write in pseudo-code

```
int[] z = new int[3];
for (int i =0; i< x.length;i++)
z[i] = x[i] * y[i];
```

But these are not matrices, if you want matrices you have to do this

```
int [ ] [ ] x= new int [ 2 ] [ 2 ] ;
int [ ] [ ] y= new int [ 2 ] [ 2 ] ;
int [ ] [ ] z= new int [ 2 ] [ 2 ] ;
//Initialize the 2 matrices with values
for(int i=0;i<x[0].length;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<y.length;j++){
       z[i][j] = x[i][j] * y[j][i];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    multiplicationOfRowsAndColumns[i] = row[i] * column[i]; 
}
```

This would do waht you want to do.